# Android: "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

Tags: android

While running my application, I received the following error:

> Android: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
>
> trouble processing "javax/net/SocketFactory.class":

Answer (score 1):

It get fixed for me when I unchecked build automatically in eclipse (Projects-> Build Automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Either you have the source code to `javax.net.SocketFactory` in your project, or your build path is messed up and it is trying to include that Java class from a JAR somewhere.